# Python Job Service Daemon?

Tags: python

What packages should I look at for writing a python daemon and processing jobs?  Also, what do I need to do for a python daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but I'm assuming you mean you would like to write a python daemon that will process jobs that get thrown in a queue.  If not, please say as much. :-)

I've heard a lot of great things about redis.  The folks at github built [resque](http://github.com/defunkt/resque) as a job processing daemon for Ruby.  If you're language flexible, you could just use that, but if you're not, you could emulate it in as much or as little depth as you like making use of  [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) as your queue system.  Depending on how pluggable and extensible you need it to be, this could be a really simple thing to implement.

Another option I ran across after some more googling is [redqueue](http://github.com/superisaac/redqueue).  It looks like it might already implement most of a job queue.

If you're using django, you may wish to consider the [Celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery/0.6.0) project.  It's a job queue system based on RabbitMQ which is yet another queuing server with excellent reviews.

As far as creating a daemon in python, there are a number of options.  You can look at this [page on activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731-creating-a-daemon-the-python-way/), which is a good start.  Better yet, you can use [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) to do it all for you.  But if you use one of the above options or beanstalkd as recommended by mczepiel, you probably won't have to make your process run as a daemon.

Comment: i saw python-daemon, is it stable enough yet?

Comment: I believe so, but I haven't taken the time to read its code or anything so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty happy with beanstalkd, which has client libraries available in various languages:

Daemon:
http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/

Python client library:
http://code.google.com/p/pybeanstalk/

Answer (score 1):

I have recently (this week) implemented a queue in RabbitMQ with a python daemon extracting the information and storing it on a database (using Django ORM). The daemon has a intermediate buffer so it will wait a little and write in the database in batches, instead of writing each time a little message arrives.

I've made the integration with the queue using this little [flopsy](http://nathanborror.com/posts/2009/may/20/working-django-and-rabbitmq/) module, which is easy to set up. The only problem I've got it to be able to set up a timeout for waiting a message, as the module has not a clear way of doing that. After a while playing with the interactive shell and making a few `dir()`, I manage to get to the `socket` object and set up the timeout.

I considered also [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/), but seems to be more focused on using internally a RabbitMQ to allow you to launch tasks (periodically or asynchronously), more that using a queue to communicating with other systems. In our case, the queue can be feed both by Python systems and Ruby ones.

Once I've completed the process, I've made some adjustments to allow running it as a daemon (mostly storing the standard output to a file to allow easy logging) and then create a bash script that launch a [start-stop-daemon](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon) command. I've followed more or less this [schema](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2010/python-daemon-init-script.html)
I discovered [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) just about one day late, so after the work is done it makes no sense revisiting it, but maybe it makes more sense for a Python project.